# How to use aggregate combinators ForEach + If

Tags: clickhouse

In ClickHouse I can change the way aggregation works with combinators.

the ForEach combinator aggregates the results over each element in an array:

```
SELECT avgForEach(array)
FROM test
```

The If combinator can be used to perform conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT avgIf(col, col > 0)
FROM test
```

But how can I use them in combination with each other to check whether each array element matches some condition before aggregating the value?

I tried using lambda functions as the conditional, but that didn't work e.g.:

```
SELECT avgForEachIf(array, x -> x > 0)
FROM test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If combinator expects simple expression

you can use a trick with Null (aggregate functions don't take into account Nulls)

```sql
SELECT avgForEach(arrayMap(x -> if(x > 0, x, NULL), a))
FROM
(
    SELECT [1, 2, 3, -5] AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [1, 1, 1, 1]
)
┌─avgForEach(arrayMap(lambda(tuple(x), if(greater(x, 0), x, NULL)), a))─┐
│ [1,1.5,2,1]                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Yeah this did the trick for me. It is a lot more intuitive to use then the `avgForEachIf` syntax

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, a coworker pointed out I was using the `ForEach` and `If` combinators in the wrong order. If you prepend the `If` it will evaluate on each array element. If you append the `If` it will evaluate the array as a whole.

Using that, you can create an array with boolean values indicating whether each element matches a condition with the `IfForEach` combinator:

```
WITH arrayJoin([[1, 1], [-1, 2]]) AS A
SELECT avgIfForEach(A, arrayMap(x -> (x > 0), A))

┌─avgIfForEach(A, arrayMap(lambda(tuple(x), greater(x, 0)), A))─┐
│ [1,1.5]                                                       │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Very nice catch. I did not think about it.